# Need a little help learning AJAX & PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

Firstly please forgive me if this is a dumb question! I've just started trying to understand what this Ajax stuff is all about with PHP by following a few online tutorials, but I dont get how you can call a javascript function which will start your ajax.

So I have a file index.html and in the body I have a function to initate an ajax request

```
<body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxFunction(){
          var ajaxRequest;
    try{
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e){

       try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
       }

       catch (e) {
            try{
               ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e){
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
            }
      }
    }
```

Then I define something to handle changes in the readystate:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4) {
document.getElementById("requestStatus").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;                
    }
}
```

Next I have a Javascript function to call ajax:

```
function archiveEvent(eventId) {
     var queryString =  "?date=" + eventId;
     ajaxRequest.open("GET", "archive.php" + queryString,true);
     ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

Then in my HTML I have a couple of divs:

```
<div id="outer">
     <input type="button" id="archive" value="Archive" onclick="WHAT DO I PUT HERE">
</div>

<div>
     <p id="requestStatus"><p>
</div>
```

The question is what do I put for the onClick value? I want to call the function archiveEvent with a parameter of say "09122014". In the tutorials ive read it says to put ajaxFunction here.

When I omitted archiveEvent function and just used hard coded values, this worked fine, but obviously I can't used hard coded values.

Comment: `onclick="ajaxFunction()"` but you probably don't need that archiveevent function

Comment: also seriously look at doing it with jquery it'll save you a crap tonne of headache you can do stuff like this `$("input#addwastemangementoption").click(function () { $.ajax({ });
    });`

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="javascript:archiveEvent(parameters)"
```

Make sure you add whatever data your function is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 <input type="button" id="archive" value="Archive" onclick='ajaxFunction()'>
```

but i'll suggest to try using `jquery ajax`.

like this on click event or any:

```
$.ajax({
type="post",
   url: archive.php,
data:{date:eventId},
success:function(){
//response here,
}
});
```